# Prove formally that $\frac {n^2 + 2}{3n^3 - 5n}\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, formal-proofs

I'm reviewing some Sequences notes from a Mathematics Analysis course I'm taking. I'm finding the beginning of the formal proof below confusing. Some clarity on the following questions would be much appreciated.

## Questions

- Why is $n\ge3$ noted? If it is to make $\frac {n^2+2}{3n^3 -5n}$ positive, why not use $n\ge2$?
- How does one arrive at $\frac {n^2+2}{3n^3 -5n} \lt \frac {n^2+2}{2n^3}$? Where does $\frac {n^2+2}{2n^3}$ come from?

## Formal Proof

[image: A formal proof from course notes]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $n \geqslant 3$ then $n^3 > 5n$ which implies $3n^3 -5n  > 2n^3$. This is not true if $n = 2$.

Therefore,

$$\frac{n^2+2}{3n^3 -5n} < \frac{n^2+2}{2n^3}.$$

We also have $2 < 2n^2$ for $n \geqslant 2$ which implies $n^2 + 2 < n^2 +2n^2 = 3n^2$.

Hence if $n \geqslant 3$,

$$\frac{n^2+2}{3n^3 -5n} < \frac{3n^2}{2n^3} = \frac{3}{2n} .$$

Comment: Are $2n^3$ (in the denominator) and $2n^2$ terms both arbitrary choices? Well, so long as the left-hand side is less than the right of the inequality in question?

Comment: Not arbitrary - just well chosen.

Comment: This should demystify the selection. You are trying to show this fraction is $O(1/n)$. We want a bound that looks like $An^2/Bn^3 = A/Bn$. Looking at the denominator we see $3n^3 -5n = 2n^3 +(n^3-5n)$ so if $n$ is big enough $n^3-5n$ is positive and the fraction is less than a fraction with only $2n^3$ in the denominator.

Comment: Thanks, that clarified it for me :)

Comment: You're very welcome